# Cyrillic sans font in beamer (LyX)

Tags: beamer, lyx, sans-serif, cyrillic, font-encodings

I am trying to use Cyrillic sans-serif font in a beamer presentation. I make it using LyX 2.0.0.
The code produced by LyX (exported as plain LaTeX) is

```
%% LyX 2.0.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[russian]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyrtext}{%
  \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{T2A}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textcyr}[1]{\leavevmode{\cyrtext #1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareFontEncoding{T2A}{}{}}

%% A simple dot to overcome graphicx limitations
\newcommand{\lyxdot}{.}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
 % this default might be overridden by plain title style
 \newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
 \AtBeginDocument{
   \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
   \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
   \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
 }
 \long\def\lyxframe#1{\@lyxframe#1\@lyxframestop}%
 \def\@lyxframe{\@ifnextchar<{\@@lyxframe}{\@@lyxframe<*>}}%
 \def\@@lyxframe<#1>{\@ifnextchar[{\@@@lyxframe<#1>}{\@@@lyxframe<#1>[]}}
 \def\@@@lyxframe<#1>[{\@ifnextchar<{\@@@@@lyxframe<#1>[}{\@@@@lyxframe<#1>[<*>][}}
 \def\@@@@@lyxframe<#1>[#2]{\@ifnextchar[{\@@@@lyxframe<#1>[#2]}{\@@@@lyxframe<#1>[#2][]}}
 \long\def\@@@@lyxframe<#1>[#2][#3]#4\@lyxframestop#5\lyxframeend{%
   \frame<#1>[#2][#3]{\frametitle{#4}#5}}
 \def\lyxframeend{} % In case there is a superfluous frame end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{listings}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usepackage{helvet}
% or ...
%\usetheme{Antibes} % tree outline, neat
%\usetheme{JuanLesPins} % like Antibes, with shading
%\usetheme{Bergen}  % outline on side
%\usetheme{Luebeck} % like Warsaw, square sides
%\usetheme{Berkeley}    % interesting left bar outline
%\usetheme{Madrid}  % clean, nice.  7/12 page numbers
%\usetheme{Berlin}  % dots show slide number
%\usetheme{Malmoe}  % OK, plain, unshaded
%\usetheme{Boadilla}    % nice, white bg, no top bar
%\usetheme{Marburg} % nice, outline on right
%\usetheme{boxes}   % ???
%\usetheme{Montpellier} % tree outline on top, plainish white
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}  % like Warsaw
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}    % looks good
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}   % like Warsaw with circle outline
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{default}
%\usetheme{Rochester}   % like boxy, unshaded warsaw
%\usetheme{Dresden} % circle outline on top
%\usetheme{Singapore}   % purple gradient top
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}   % like Warsaw with circle outline on top
%\usetheme{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Goettingen}  % light purple right bar outline
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usetheme{Hannover}    % like Goett with bar on left
%\usetheme{compatibility}
%\usetheme{Ilmenau}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
% or whatever (possibly just delete it)

%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\usecolortheme{rose}

% seems to fix typewriter font in outline header:
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
%\pgfdeclareimage[height=1cm]{institution-logo}{hint-logo-mn.jpg}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title[Высокогорные леса]{Историческое использование\\высокогорных лесов}


\subtitle{современное значение\\на государственном и местном уровнях}


\author[S\o{}veig; Наумов]{Robert S\o{}veig, Владимир Наумов}


\institute{Niht}


\date{5 сентября 2012}

\makebeamertitle
%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}


\lyxframeend{}\lyxframe{Robert S\o{}veig}

\begin{center}
\par\end{center}
\begin{block}
{}
\begin{itemize}
\item место работы: 
\item специализация:
\item опыт:
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\note[item]{Начало доклада}


\note[item]{Теперь я перейду собственно к нашему докладу.}


\lyxframeend{}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the font in the output is not sans-serif, although I know that by default beamer uses sans serif font. F.ex. this code:

```
\documentclass[russian]{beamer}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    ПРИВЕТ! Этот текст написан шрифтом без засечек.
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

works flawlessly in plain LaTeX.

I suppose that the problem is in font encoding.

How to force LyX to use correct font encoding, e.g. to produce beamer presentation with sans serif cyrillic fonts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first code example is rather messy and, in my opinion, a good demostration why LyX should *not* be used as it complicates things rather than simplifying them.

In the second code you are forgetting to load `babel`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    ПРИВЕТ! Этот текст написан шрифтом без засечек.
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In general I prefer to pass the language option to `babel` rather than to the class (you may have surprises if you want to use multiple languages).

[image]

Here's a "more correct" version of the first code (I used `utf8` instead of `koi8-r`). The `ae` and `aecompl` packages are obsolete.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

% \usepackage{listings}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\title[Высокогорные леса]{Историческое использование\\высокогорных лесов}


\subtitle{современное значение\\на государственном и местном уровнях}


\author[S\o{}veig; Наумов]{Robert S\o{}veig, Владимир Наумов}


\institute{Niht}


\date{5 сентября 2012}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Robert S\o{}veig}

\begin{block}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item место работы: 
\item специализация:
\item опыт:
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\note[item]{Начало доклада}


\note[item]{Теперь я перейду собственно к нашему докладу.}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. What do you advise to use instead of LyX? Text editors like vi?

Comment: @VladimirNaumov Definitely a (La)TeX front end; if you're comfortable with `vi`, it has a "TeX mode". But something like TeXStudio or TeXworks can get you started.